# How did the term "space" in mathematics started to be understood as a set with a structure?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, terminology

In mathematical literature, the term 'space' is often used to describe a set endowed with additional structure, such as a metric space or a vector space. What is the historical evolution of the concept of 'space' in mathematics, specifically its formalization as a set with particular properties?" In modern books the term is not explicitly defined, even in early books of 1947, like Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces, a vector space is defined as a set with certain axioms while avoiding to define what "space" itself is.

Searching plenty of older Google Books with keywords, "the term space" or "the word space" in mathematics led to one book that explicitly opened with the following:

*Linear Transformations in Hilbert Space and Their Applications to Analysis* by Marshall Harvey Stone (1932)

> *§. The Concept of Space The word "space" has gradually acquired a
> mathematical significance so broad that it is rirtually equivalent to
> the word "class", as used in logic. Historically, the reason for" this
> development is to be found in the recognition that many classes which
> are of special importance in mathematics enjoy internal properties
> analogous to the familiar ones of Euclidean space. For example, the
> class of all continuous real functions of a real variable defined on a
> given closed interval can be treated as a metric space, the distance
> between two functions of the class being the maximum numerical value
> of their difference. Another class or space of peculiar importance for
> analysis is the class of all real functions of a real variable on a
> given closed interval which are Lebesgue-measurable and have
> Lebesgue-integrable squares; in this space, the distance between two
> elements or points of the space may be defined as the square root of
> the integral of the square of their difference. In each of these two
> cases, the distance between two elements or points of the space has
> many of the properties of distance in Euclidean geometry. Spaces such
> as those just described are frequently referred to as
> "function-spaces" or "spaces of infinitely many dimensions".*

Can anyone provide a reference which shows the earliest of the term space as used in modern times? In the unabridged version of Oxford English Dictionary, the earliest use of space in mathematical sense in English is 1900 as

> 1900 *One speaks of the geometries of metric space, of unilateral and
> bilateral projective space. American Journal of Mathematics vol. 22
> 336.*

Most likely the current usage of space and structure must have come either from German or French works.

Comment: the MacTutor web site on "Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics" indeed lists your 1932 source: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/s/

Comment: It was Fréchet in (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03018603)

Comment: @user234212323, The article has 72 pages in French. Do you know the relevant page? I can get that translated.

Comment: Thanks for the leads to Frechet. I found a Dover's Book Great Currents of Mathematical Thought. Volume I where he has full chapter on "From Three-Dimensional Spaces to the Abstract Spaces." The term structure also originates from (geometrical) structure. I am not a mathematician by training but a user of its applications! The elusive nature of the terms space and structure was bothersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web page http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Axiomatization_of_the_manifold_concept attributes the earliest definition to M. Fréchet (per user234212323's comment) and to F. Riesz.

Comment: Thanks, in your provided link, there is an 2006 thesis dedicated to the concept of space. It is in German but machine translation is pretty good of the initial pages.  "L. Rodriguez, Friedrich Riesz' Beiträge zur Herausbildung des modernen mathematischen Konzepts abstrakter Räume. Synthese intellektueller Kulturen in Ungarn, Frankreich und Deutschland, Dissertationsschrift Universität Mainz 2006. (Contributions to the formation of the modern mathematical concept of abstract spaces. Synthesis of Intellectual Cultures in Hungary, France and Germany).

Comment: I found the link by looking for references to H. Whitney's work on the definition of a differentiable manifold, as I (erroneously) thought that his work contained the definition you were seeking.